# Quartz2D and Clipping - Optimize this drawing routine?

Tags: iphone

I'm new to Quartz2d so I hope this is an easy question to answer.

I have a scrollview whose content frame is 1024x768.  Within this I push a custom view (with frame 1024x768)  that uses Quartz2d to do some drawing.  The idea is, I have a large area that the user can scroll around to see different parts.

The problem I'm having is, when I scroll on the device I get memory warning errors or terrible scrolling performance.  This is no doubt because I am re-drawing the entire 1024x768 field.  I thought that setting the clipping path to the UIScrollView offset would help.. and it does.. until i scroll.. in which case the view does not redraw until scrolling stops.  telling the view to draw during scrollViewDidScroll also results in bad performance

can anyone tell me how i can optimize my drawing routine?

i have two images.. one of which is getting masked, and both being painted to the screen (one on top of the other)

`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {`

```
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// get our offset (where we've scrolled to)
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    // clip to our offset.. uncomment for good performance but terrible scrolling
//CGContextClipToRect(myContext, CGRectMake(offset.x, offset.y, 480, 320));


// make an image from the mask context
CGImageRef aMaskImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (myMaskContext);

// mask the first image
CGImageRef aImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(myImageRef1, aMaskImage);

CGContextDrawImage(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), myImageRef1);
CGContextDrawImage(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), aImage);


CGImageRelease(aImage);
CGImageRelease(aMaskImage);
```

}

thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally to optimize scrolling big stuff you'd look into CATiledLayer.

Comment: thanks.  i haven't the time to look at this anymore, but i am awarding this as the answer as it is the only one and seems reasonable.  :)

Comment: I suppose the other answer is to observe the dirtyRect argument, but I think CATiledLayer is more likely to help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume somewhere you call `setNeedsDisplay`. You need to call `setNeedsDisplayInRect`. Make sure to only pass the rect that changed.